# How do I read and parse a .dat file in C?

Tags: c

I have a file called `resistors.dat` and I need to get my program to read and parse the values from the file into my program.

How would I read a file like this in C?

> Read from the le resistors.dat (supplied on Blackboard) similarly to what you have done in Problem 2 of Lab 12. Each line in resistors.dat now represents one row: Ria, Rib and Ric (i = 1; 2; : : : ; n) of the circuit. Expand Problem 2 of Lab 12 to calculate the total resistance of the circuit. Hint: The total resistance is given by 1 R = 1 R1 + 1 R2 + 1 R3 + : : : + 1 Rn where Ri is the sum of resistances in one input row. In a loop, compute the sum of the inverse resistances 1=Ri. After the input has finished, compute the inverse of this sum to obtain the final result.

This is the content of `resistors.dat`:

```
64.35 35.52 85.37 
90.43 12.99 80.40 
98.37 32.63 78.42 
3.82 82.74 52.61 
3.75 72.47 49.05 
96.73 16.07 23.46 
48.15 36.62 83.64 
51.96 27.19 22.38 
4.18 46.07 91.21 
96.94 8.17 50.45 
0
```

Comment: Take a look into file reading methods in C - fgets and fgetc to mention a few.

Comment: How was the .dat file created?
If its as simple text file(verify by opening with notepad)
Then you can open it as a normal txt. If it was as bytes you'll need to pass it through a stream to process it.
Provide more details for a more clear answer. [Parsing files in C](http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/657086-how-parse-file-c) Should give you a starting point towards your end but some more information would help give a much more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this. I expect that your `Resistors.dat` file looks something like this:

```
r=1
r=20
r=22
r=2
```

I suggest you do something like this:

`fopen` to open the file, `fgets` in a `while` loop until the end of the file (`!EOF`), to read each line. Then use `sscanf` to parse each line.